# How do I do a bind mount over a symlink?

Tags: linux, mount, symlink

I have a symlink:

```
/test
```

Which is pointing at a directory:

```
/source
```

I want to do a bind mount to mount /new over /test

```
mount -o bind /new /test
```

However this binds /new over /source (with /test pointing at /source - showing the files from /new, but not what I want). How do I stop mount following the symlink and get it to  mount at /test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since /test is not a real directory, this won't work.
Unlink it, create it as a real directory, then do the bind mount.

Comment: You can use bind mounts to replace one file with another, but it appears that when the target is a symlink, the kernel expands it before doing the bind mount :(

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create bindmount over symlinks with new Linux kernel mount API. Here is an example:

```
unshare -m
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp
cd /tmp
echo TEST1 > test1
echo TEST2 > test2
ln -s test1 symlink1
ln -s test2 symlink2
cat symlink1
# TEST1
cat symlink2
# TEST2
bindmount-v2 symlink1 symlink2
# Mounting symlink1 into symlink2
cat symlink2
# TEST1
cat /proc/self/mountinfo | grep symlink
# 2221 2323 0:120 /symlink1 /tmp/symlink2 rw,relatime - tmpfs tmpfs rw,inode64
```

This uses simple C program `bindmount-v2`, source https://github.com/Snorch/linux-helpers/blob/master/bindmount-v2.c

I'm not aware about any attempt to add this to mount utility.

Only supported on v5.12+ kernels. AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW is a key part to create bindmounts on top of symlinks. If you drop mount_setattr related hunks, which is probably not important for your case you would be able to do the same on v5.2+ kernels.

note: Symlink can not be bindmounted to or from directory.